# How to get rid of space before and after series in chart winforms?

Tags: c#, windows

[image]
How to get rid of that space in chart?

Adding values:

```
s = chart1.Series[0];
for (int i = 0; i < Mess.Count; i++) { //List with data and value
    tec_time = DateTime.MinValue;
    DateTime.TryParse(Mess[i][1].ToString(), out tec_time);
    s.Points.AddXY(tec_time.ToLocalTime().ToOADate(), double.Parse(Mess[i][2]));
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the boundaries of your graph, basically the minimum values for the X,Y. I'd say this property should lie on the "chart1" object.

Comment: Its isn't helping. Btw ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum has already right value (which is first green dot)